# (Game bug) Tetris pieces being disappearing when colliding

Tags: javascript, tetris

I'm making a Tetris game with javascript, but there's a bug I haven't been able to fix yet. It only happens when pieces Z, S, and T collide with an object while going down. I thought the problem was with the 3rd row of 0s, but the other pieces draw fine when I add it to other pieces. I also can't remove the rows because I need them to rotate the pieces.

If anyone can find the error I'd really appreciate it! Thank you.

Here's the code on repl.it:
https://repl.it/@julkothegu1/Oke-Oke

Raw:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('tetris');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.scale(20, 20);

function arena_sweep(){
  let row_count = 1
  outer: for (let y = arena.length -1; y > 0; y--){
    for (let x = 0; x < arena[y].length; x++){
      if (arena[y][x] == 0){
        continue outer
      }
    }

    const row = arena.splice(y, 1)[0].fill(0);
    arena.unshift(row);
    ++y;

    player.score += row_count * 10
    row_count *= 2
  }
}

function draw(){
  context.fillStyle = '#000';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  draw_matrix(arena, {x:0, y:0})
  draw_matrix(player.matrix, player.pos)
}

function create_matrix(w, h){
  const matrix = []
  while (h--){
    matrix.push(new Array(w).fill(0))
  }
  return matrix
}

function player_reset(){
  const pieces = 'ILJOZST'
  player.matrix = create_piece(pieces[pieces.length * Math.random() | 0])
  player.pos.y = 0
  player.pos,x = (arena[0].length / 2 | 0) - (player.matrix[0].length / 2 | 0)
  if (collide(arena, player)){
    arena.forEach(row => row.fill(0))
    player.score = 0
    update_score()
  }
}

function create_piece(type)
{
    if (type === 'I') {
        return [
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 0, 0],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'L') {
        return [
            [0, 2, 0],
            [0, 2, 0],
            [0, 2, 2],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'J') {
        return [
            [0, 3, 0],
            [0, 3, 0],
            [3, 3, 0],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'O') {
        return [
            [4, 4],
            [4, 4],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'Z') {
        return [
            [5, 5, 0],
            [0, 5, 5],
            [0, 0, 0],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'S') {
        return [
            [0, 6, 6],
            [6, 6, 0],
            [0, 0, 0],
        ];
    } else if (type === 'T') {
        return [
            [0, 7, 0],
            [7, 7, 7],
            [0, 0, 0],
        ];
    }
}

function draw_matrix(matrix, offset){
  matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((value, x) => {
      if (value !== 0){
        context.fillStyle = colors[value]
        context.fillRect(x + offset.x, y + offset.y, 1, 1)
      }
    });
  });
}

function merge(arena, player){
  player.matrix.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((value, x) => {
      if (value !== 0){
        arena[y + player.pos.y][x + player.pos.x] = value;
      }
    });
  });
}

function collide(arena, player){
  const m = player.matrix;
  const o = player.pos;

  for (let y = 0; y < m.length; y++){
    for (let x = 0; x < m[y].length; x++){
      if (m[y][x] != 0 && (arena[y + o.y] && arena[y + o.y][x + o.x]) != 0){
        return true
      }
    }
  }
  return false
}

let drop_counter = 0
let last_time = 0
let drop_interval = 400

function update(time = 0){
  const delta_time = time - last_time
  drop_counter += delta_time

  if (drop_counter > drop_interval){
    player_drop()
  }

  last_time = time
  draw()
  requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

function player_drop(){
  player.pos.y++
  if (collide(arena, player)){
    player.pos.y--
    merge(arena, player)
    player_reset()
    arena_sweep()
    update_score()
  }
  drop_counter = 0
}

function player_move(dir){
  player.pos.x += dir
  if (collide(arena, player)){
    player.pos.x -= dir
  }
}

function player_rotate(dir){
  const pos = player.pos.x
  let offset = 1
  rotate(player.matrix, dir)
  while (collide(arena, player)){
    player.pos.x += offset
    offset = -(offset + (offset > 0 ? 1 : -1))
    if (offset > player.matrix[0].length){
      rotate(player.matrix, -dir)
      player.pos.x = pos
      return
    }
  }
}

function update_score(){
  document.getElementById('score').innerText = player.score
}

function rotate(matrix, dir){
  for (let y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++){
    for (let x = 0; x < y; x++){
      [
        matrix[x][y],
        matrix[y][x],
      ] = [
        matrix[y][x],
        matrix[x][y],
      ];
    }
  }
  if (dir > 0){
    matrix.forEach(row => row.reverse());
  } else {
    matrix.reverse();
  }
}

const colors = [ 
  null,
  'green',
  'blue',
  'violet',
  'red',
  'purple',
];

const player = {
  pos: {x: 0, y: 0},
  matrix: null,
  score: 0,
}

const arena = create_matrix(12, 20)

document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  if (event.keyCode === 37){
    player_move(-1);
  }else if (event.keyCode == 39){
    player_move(1);
  }else if (event.keyCode == 40){
    player_drop();
  }else if (event.keyCode == 81){
    player_rotate(-1)
  }else if (event.keyCode == 87){
    player_rotate(1)
  }
});

update_score()
player_reset()
update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found the error. I forgot to give 7 colors to the pieces, so it was looping on colors it shouldn't have been.